# Gradle Upgrade from 4 to 7, Sharing tests between modules

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I am upgrading our multi module build from gradle 4.10 to 7.1 Kotlin DSL. Test module (Cucumber tests) is dependent on main module and its tests.

Test Module is dependent on core module,

Test Module configuration (Gradle 4)

```
    compile project(path: ":core", configuration: 'testCompile')
    // include test classes from core
    compile project(':core').sourceSets.test.output
```

Gradle 7 doesnt support getting sourceset directly from another module, also I cant direcly pull the “testImplementation” configuration from another module.

Please help

Comment: see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/cross_project_publications.html#cross_project_publications

Comment: Also, I'd recommend updating gradually - [from 4 to 5](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_4.html), [from 5 to 6](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html), [from 6 to 7](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html) fixing all deprecation warnings on each step